# Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Received empty image data response

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio, visual-recognition

I am using Watson Studio to build a Visual Recognition model for detecting weed in plants images by using Object detection.

When I try to label more images for my custom object detection it pops up this error:

```
An error occurred while updating IMG_20160626_164256.jpg
Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Received empty image data response.
```

It was working before but when I came back to continue from where I stop I started having an error. i have checked my location and it is correct.

My question is why I my getting this error  and how I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem Pedro. Did you find a solution?